# Yum update stucks inside docker

Tags: docker, yum

I have installed Docker 20.10 on RHEL 9 system, and installed CentOS 7 container on docker. But when I tried `yum update` on it, it takes a long time while running transaction, as if yum stuck while updating.
[Yum update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03sUh.png)

I tried `strace -p 6351` to see what is happening inside yum, and it endlessly says `fnctl(765158398, F_GETFD) = -1 EBADF (Bad File Descriptor)` [strace -p 6351](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n518w.png)

Same thing happens when I tried `yum install openssh-server`, but `yum install telnet` worked fine.

I really want to know what is happening on my docker. Any idea to fix it??

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I have found that `ulimit -n`, `ulimit -Hn`, `ulimit -Sn` value inside the container was 1073741824, and it made yum check every possible file descriptor, from 0 to 1073741824.

I have inserted `--ulimit nofile=1024:262144` in docker commandline (like `docker run --ulimit nofile=1024:262144 --name test -p 2202:22/tcp -i -t centos:7 /bin/bash`), and `yum update` worked fine! Now I can enjoy yum on docker happily!

Answer (score 0):

Is there also a solution without setting it in every docker container and maybe in containerd? I am experiencing similar issues in centos 7.9 containers running on centos 9 hosts using Kubernetes/containerd. Yum installations take hours instead of minutes.

Update: I've added LimitNOFILE=1048576 to the service unit of containerd now and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).